# Importing and making an image the background of my program

Tags: java, image

How would I import an image and make it the background of my program?

I have tried the drawing method but it failed.

```
package Control;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Control extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Control() {
        setSize(500, 500);
        setTitle("Asteroid: Save Humanity");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Control();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your code in which you actually tied to make image background?

Answer (score 0):

To make a JPanel with a backround, check out [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Panelwithbackgroundimage.htm) link. It's fairly simple, just create a new instance of this class, it will behave like a JPanel. You can always modify it so that the you set the content pane to this image. If nothing else, use it for reference.

Basicly, it creates a new instance of `Image` from a String or `ImageIcon`, and uses `drawImage()` to render it.

Answer (score 0):

Make jframe operations in main method and use jpanel for making background.
Use paintComponent  for drawing image or use image icon.